# Use Gulp to check if a token exists in a file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-replace

If I do this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('TaskExample', function ReplaceExampleFileTokens() {

    return gulp.src('./src/' + 'ExampleFileTokens.config')

        .pipe(replace('#{String}#', 'Hello World'))
        .pipe(rename('ExampleFile.config'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
    });
```

I will:

1. replace the token in `ExampleFileTokens.config` then
2. rename it to `ExampleFile.config` and
3. finally deposit it in `'./dest'`.

My questions are the following:

- How would you check that `#{String}#` exists in
  `ExampleFileTokens.config` without using gulp.dest if the token
  doesn't exist?
- I know I could search the file in javascript with the token, but is there a way with maybe `gulp-replace`, since it's already searching and replacing my tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to have gulp-replace do all the work you want.  It is troublesome to set a conditional within a stream.

You can do it easily enough with a filter though ([gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter).

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const filterEach = require('gulp-filter-each')

gulp.task("TaskExample", function () {

  // return true if want the file in the stream
  // const configFilter = filter(function (file) {       
  //   let contents = file.contents.toString();
  //   return contents.match('#{String}#');
  // });

  return gulp.src('./src/' + 'ExampleFileTokens.config')

    // you can use either of the following two filters
    // .pipe(configFilter)
    .pipe(filterEach(content => content.match('#{String}#')))

    .pipe(replace('#{String}#', 'Hello World'))
    .pipe(rename('ExampleFile.config'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest'));
});
```